# Early implementations of the `system()` call in a consumer OS

Tags: ms-dos, unix, cp-m, mac-os-classic, multitasking

Nowadays, it's easy to take for granted [the system() call](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html) (as defined in [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX)), which allows a user program to easily execute a child process and wait for it to complete. Obviously, this is a trivial (*and* useful!) API to implement on a multitasking OS, such as the original Unix. I'm curious about the same capability being available to applications running on *early consumer operating systems*<sup>1</sup>, which  were not based on Unix and didn't support multitasking<sup>2</sup>.

I would stipulate that the OS would need to provide an API that makes it just as trivial to invoke a child process as the `system()` call. Therefore, it would also transparently protect the memory of the calling program from being corrupted by a well-behaved child process *(**not** meaning hardware enforced protected memory here)*. Multitasking systems have a general approach to sharing memory. This would, I assume, be a more limited mechanism that restores memory to the way it was when the call returns to the parent.

Did such an API exist on early single-tasking OS's like [CP/M](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CP/M), DOS, [MacOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classic_Mac_OS), [Atari TOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atari_TOS), etc.? Is there a more obscure consumer system with OS that provided it earlier?

<sup>1</sup> I'm talking about an OS for a low-cost "personal computer" as one might have found in common use by small business or home computer hobbyists.

<sup>2</sup> The Amiga was released in 1985 and had the `Execute()` API for this—it doesn't count, because it's also a multitasking OS.

Comment: On the *original* UNIX, I'm not sure it would have been that easy. ISTR it had a single process slot per terminal and the program switch was more like MSDOS where exit() simply loaded the shell back over the current program in the slot.

Comment: @paxdiablo I thought `fork()` and its variations for process management were there pretty early in Unix history. I haven't found a reference for when the actual `system()` function appeared.

Comment: Depends on your definition of early :-) See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091254/who-know-the-history-of-unix-fork

Comment: Also keep in mind that with little memory available, it makes much more sense to put the "call other programs" functionality in a shell/command processor/batch processing facility instead of the operating system, so many early single-tasking OS did exactly that.

Comment: Trivial?  I do not think it means what you think it means. 

Comment: And CP/M did not do anything like that.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen Trival==heavily abstracted, in this context. Someone has already done the work to make the API available and easy to use.

Comment: Useful? I do not think it means what you think it means.

Comment: The constraint about protecting the calling program pretty much eliminates, well, everything that this post is asking about. Since none of those systems had any memory protection at all. Even OS/9 couldn't due that, even though it was, indeed, a mutli-tasking system. But programs still had to be well behaved to get along with others.

Comment: @WillHartung I did not mean to suggest "memory protection" as a constraint. Just that the mechanism would sufficiently maintain the state of the calling program so that things work fine for well-behaved programs- just like with OS/9 or AmigaOS.

Comment: But what 'state' is there in something as simple as DOS?  Is it necessary to preserve registers across this ur-fork call?  Why?  There are systems where registers aren't preserved across a simple subroutine call.  PC and (if you've got one) a stack seem to be the only actual requirements.

Comment: @another-dave I think you are assuming that the called program cannot/would not load into an area of memory already occupied by the calling program. I was not assuming that in the question, and see no reason that _must_ be the case.

Comment: It is interesting to consider this as the evolution from invoking a subroutine to invoking larger abstractions.

Comment: nitpick: You know `system()` is a library function, not a "system call" on normal Unix systems, right?  The implementation of `system` on a system like Linux involves multiple system calls, to at least `fork(2)`, `execve(2)`, and some flavour of `wait`.  "*`system()` call*" is a fun and compact way to write it, but not accurate.

Comment: @BrianH: Per the [Unix Archive](https://www.tuhs.org/archive_sites.html), V1 Unix already had system calls named `fork` and `exec` (though according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5091254/who-know-the-history-of-unix-fork they may not have had quite the same functionality as today).  On the other hand, I didn't see `system()` appearing until V6.

Comment: It's always been my general impression that `system()` was added to the standard C library later on, partly just as a convenient way to call fork/exec/wait with a single function, but also because it was a "least common denominator" that C implementations on non-Unix systems could still support.  As noted in answers, it was entirely possible for single-tasking OSes like MS-DOS to implement `system()`, while `fork()/exec()` would have been impossible.  Much later, POSIX introduced `posix_spawn` for similar reasons (for the benefit of Windows, I always guessed).

Comment: @NateEldredge: I suspect also that the fork/exec paradigm existed before there was any notion of holding multiple programs in RAM at once.  Early time-sharing systems operated on the assumption that switching tasks would involve writing all of the current task's RAM to disk and then loading in a memory image of the task to run instead.  Under such a paradigm, a fork could be accomplished by writing the contents of memory to disk as though switching tasks, and then selecting a different spot to which the contents of memory will be written on the next task switch.  If a new program...

Comment: ...gets loaded during the current time slice, the cost of a fork+exec would be essentially the same as a "spawn new function" call.  The design is not so good when using an abstraction model where address space is shared among tasks. but unfortunately it's stuck around anyway.

Answer (score 20):

MS-DOS allows an application to invoke a nested application.  Processing of the former application will be suspended until the latter application returns, whereupon the former application will continue following the function call that invoked the other application.

The way this typically worked revolved around the fact that MS-DOS programs may be easily relocated to any 16-byte boundary when they are loaded, and often use storage near the end of their code space before they use storage that's higher up.  Launching a nested application simply involves having it invoked with its "low-water mark" set to equal the parent program's "high-water mark".

MS-DOS 2.0 (October 1983) and later provided this as a system call, [interrupt 0x21 service 0x4B](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/214b.html). Prior to that, program loading had to be implemented manually, albeit with some help from [interrupt 0x21 service 0x26](https://fd.lod.bz/rbil/interrup/dos_kernel/2126.html) to create a PSP; see [`COMMAND.COM`’s implementation for one example](https://github.com/microsoft/MS-DOS/blob/master/v1.25/source/COMMAND.ASM#L953) (this was trivial for `.COM`-style programs, more complex for MZ programs). Programming environments typically provided their own wrappers for service 0x4B; see for example [Turbo C’s `spawn` functions](https://archive.org/details/bitsavers_borlandturuide1987_12272000/page/n237/mode/2up), or [GW-BASIC’s `SHELL` statement](http://geocities.ws/chorimovil/manualgwbasic/SHELL.html).

Comment: Back in the DOS days I had an emacs-like editor where you could run DOS commands, compilers (and make) in one of the buffers. Not quite sure just how it worked, but it did.

Comment: @JonCuster My similar recollection is about Norton Commander, but I think that used some fancy programming to manage/resume its state.

Comment: I just checked my copy of the MSDOS FoxBase+ manual dated July 1987, and the RUN/! command existed, which allows you to run another executable from within a FoxBase program.  Not multitasking of course; the Foxbase program stopped until the other command returned.

Comment: And to circle back to the original question, just a few pages later on in the Turbo C manual, we indeed have an entry for `system()`, which acts as more or less a wrapper around `spawn()`.

Comment: @JonCuster I recall Turbo Pascal's Turbo Vision also has some demo that pause the text editor and return to DOS then resume

Answer (score 13):

All versions of Atari's GEMDOS (first released in 1985) supported [Pexec()](https://freemint.github.io/tos.hyp/en/gemdos_process.html#Pexec).  Flags permitted launching the child process and waiting for it to finish, or merely loading the child into memory (for overlays and debugging).

Comment: I'm curious why the same page (which might be about FreeMint) also documents a Pfork() call. fork()/exec() style process management is quite "Unixy" and I thought GEMDOS was a close relative of CP/M-68k.

Comment: Those calls were added in later GEMDOS / TOS improvements, including MultiTOS and MiNT.  I assumed your question pertained to the earliest versions of consumer operating systems, when the ST was single-tasking.

Comment: GEMDOS is closer to MS-DOS in spirit than to CP/M. I suppose DR used their DR-DOS code for the porting more than their CP/M 68 code.

Comment: GEMDOS was apparently originally a private project by Jason Loveman, a Digital Research developer. This was before DR-DOS existed; DR's DOS-compatible operating systems at the time were DOS emulators running atop CP/M kernels.

Comment: CP/M 68K could do it

Answer (score 11):

Since you mentioned CP/M: At least in its original 8080 incarnation, CP/M does not have any system call that allows a program to launch another and regain control when the program it launched terminates. Under CP/M-80, programs are assembled to run at address 0100h, so loading the 'child' process would inevitably overwrite the memory of the 'parent'. While it's possible to imagine workarounds (such as the 'parent' process relocating itself higher in memory and reporting a reduced memory size to the 'child') there is no simple system call that does this.

The closest approximation is the [P_CHAIN](http://www.seasip.info/Cpm/bdos.html#47) call under CP/M 3, which takes a command line and executes it as if typed at the A> prompt. However this terminates the calling program before executing the command, for the reason given above.

Comment: This really isn't an answer, as it is proving that CP/M *couldn't* do it.

Comment: But it could be done...Turbo Pascal had this capability. It used it run both it's own programs, and external ones. But it was not a built-in CP/M service. It doesn't hurt that CP/M had 2 ways to exit a program. Return to the CCP, or warm start the entire OS. Of course, you could only return to the CCP if your code didn't stomp it out in memory first.

Comment: XSUB and DESPOOL were official utilities using this technique.

Comment: @WillHartung Turbo Pascal could `chain` and `execute`.  The first one launched a compiled-with-no-runtime Turbo Pascal program and the other any normal COM executable.  They did not return to the calling program as it was overwritten.   Section 22.4 on page 146 in http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/borland/turbo_pascal/TURBO_Pascal_Reference_Manual_CPM_Version_3_Dec88.pdf

Comment: @DrSheldon: The question was "Did such an API exist on early single-tasking OSs like CP/M, DOS, MacOS..." For CP/M, at least, "No" is the correct answer.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If you use the eXecute command from the Turbo Pascal menu, it will run the program and return you to Turbo Pascal. It does this even if the program you run does a warm start of the system to exit.

Comment: @WillHartung Interesting.  I did not remember that.  Did it keep Turbo Pascal in memory (including your program) or did it reread it back from disk afterwards?

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen it loads it back from disk. CP/M is already setup to reload the CCP on warm start, Turbo must "hack" the system so that it reloads Turbo instead. Turbos "state" simply it few compiler options, including the names of the main and work files. For example, it reloads the error messages when it returns.

Comment: @WillHartung: If memory serves, CCP looks for a file with a certain name when it starts, and if that file exists it will read the last 128 bytes, shorten the file by 128 bytes, and then interpret the data it read as though it were typed on the command line.

Comment: @WillHartung I never knew that Turbo Pascal can run on CP/M, although I've seen Turbo Vision has a "return to DOS" feature for running other commands temporarily

Answer (score 4):

The Cambridge Z88 (1987) has a number of system calls that allow it to

- enumerate installed programs on inserted flash cards in its 4MB address range
- Select one of the enumerated applications to run
- create and forward "Mailbox content" to applications being run
  (which can contain a "come back to (and restart) me after done")

So, essentially, all functions required to implement a `system()` call functional equivalent are present. It's obviously not presented as a POSIX-compliant implementation, though.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that it would have been useful on Mac OS unless you were writing a launcher in the brief period before the MultiFinder as applications always present at least some UI and do not exit of their own volition.

With System 7 Apple introduced AppleScript, which allows applications to expose scriptable actions and thereby allows a third-party application to interface with a scriptable application e.g. to open an audio editor, ask it to open a file, delete the first five seconds, normalise audio elsewhere, save and exit. But that's in the era where cooperative multitasking was enabled for all, rather than being a third-party extension (prior to System 5) or optional (in Systems 5 and 6).

Comment: AppleScipt is textual and can launch other programs, but isn't even close to implementing the `system()` call.  When a question asks about the first instance of a POSIX behavior, the answer is *never* classic MacOS.

Comment: I wonder how the shell utility worked in Macintosh Programmer's Workshop.

Comment: @DrSheldon agreed, but it is part of the correct answer to "Did such an API exist on early single-tasking OS's like ... MacOS"?